# Delete Columns Using Date Function

Tags: vba, excel

I apologize if I have posted this question incorrectly, I am still getting used to the StackExchange network.

I have created a user-form to duplicate a template workbook, fill in dates of a selected month and year, and then delete the extra columns because the template workbook has 31 pre-formatted columns.

The problem I am having is that when I click on the "Enter" button in the user-form, the workbook duplicates and saves, and puts the dates across the top, BUT, it does not completely execute the "delete" line under "Duplicate Sheet".  For each sheet in the workbook (Daily Sales, Total Inventory, Deliveries, Income Statement, Profits) when it puts in the dates across the top, it is supposed to delete the extra columns that are greater than "days" and less than 31 columns after the first date of the month.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
InitializeMonthsCombo
InitializeYearsCombo
End Sub
Private Sub InitializeMonthsCombo()
Dim months() As String
months =    Split("January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,_
September,October,November,December", ",")

Dim i As Integer
For i = LBound(months) To UBound(months)
    Me.CmboMonth.AddItem months(i)
Next
End Sub
Private Sub InitializeYearsCombo()

Const startYear As Integer = 2015
Const endYear As Integer = 2035

Dim i As Integer
For i = startYear To endYear
    Me.CmboYear.AddItem i
Next
End Sub
Private Sub CmdEnter_Click()
Dim Days As Integer
Dim StartDate As Date

    StartDate = CDate("1-" & CmboMonth.Value & "-" & CmboYear.Value)
    Days = (DateDiff("d", StartDate, DateAdd("m", 1, StartDate))) - 1

'Duplicate Sheet
Sheets(Array("Daily Sales", "Total Inventory", "Deliveries", "Income   
Statement", "Profits")).Copy


        'Daily Sales
        Dim DailySales As Worksheet
        Set DailySales = Worksheets("Daily Sales")

        Populate DailySales, DailySales.Range("B6"),   
        DailySales.Range(DailySales.Cells(6, 2), DailySales.Cells(6, 2 + 
            Days))
        Range(Cells(1, 3 + Days), Cells(1, 32)).EntireColumn.Delete

        'Total Inventory
        Dim TotalInventory As Worksheet
        Set TotalInventory = Worksheets("Total Inventory")

        Populate TotalInventory, TotalInventory.Range("C5"), 
         TotalInventory.Range(TotalInventory.Cells(5, 3), 
         TotalInventory.Cells(5, 3 + Days))
        Populate TotalInventory, TotalInventory.Range("C5"), 
         TotalInventory.Range(TotalInventory.Cells(5, 3), 
         TotalInventory.Cells(5, 2))
        Range(Cells(1, 4 + Days), Cells(1, 33)).EntireColumn.Delete

        'Deliveries
        Dim Deliveries As Worksheet
        Set Deliveries = Worksheets("Deliveries")

        Populate Deliveries, Deliveries.Range("B6"), 
        Deliveries.Range(Deliveries.Cells(6, 2), Deliveries.Cells(6, 2 + 
              Days))
        Range(Cells(1, 3 + Days), Cells(1, 32)).EntireColumn.Delete

        'Income Statement
        Dim IncomeStatement As Worksheet
        Set IncomeStatement = Worksheets("Income Statement")

        Populate IncomeStatement, IncomeStatement.Range("C4"), 
            IncomeStatement.Range(IncomeStatement.Cells(4, 3), 
            IncomeStatement.Cells(4, 3 + Days))
        Range(Cells(1, 4 + Days), Cells(1, 33)).EntireColumn.Delete

        'Profits
        Dim Profits As Worksheet
        Set Profits = Worksheets("Profits")

        Populate Profits, Profits.Range("E4"), 
           Profits.Range(Profits.Cells(4, 5), Profits.Cells(4, 5 + Days))
        Range(Cells(1, 6 + Days), Cells(1, 35)).EntireColumn.Delete
    End Sub
Public Sub Populate(DestSheet As Worksheet, first As Range, dest As  
Range)
    Dim StartDate As Date
    StartDate = CDate("1-" & CmboMonth.Value & "-" & CmboYear.Value)

    first.Value = StartDate
    first.AutoFill Destination:=dest, Type:=xlFillValues

    DestSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

'Close Userform
Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub CmdCancel_Click()
'Close Userform
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your issue? because in your code, you only delete the first column each time and without tests or loops, so I don't get how that can't work...

Comment: That is exactly why I am so confused and asking for help, I don't understand how it can't work either!  Is there something you can see in my code that might be influencing the "delete" command?

Comment: Except for the lack of referencing (Workbook.sheet.range), nope... It might be that you work in a new workbook after copying the sheets, so you need to specify in which one you are doing your operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem!  The issue was that when I went to delete the columns on each sheet, I was not changing the reference to that sheet, and so it was deleting the column on the active sheet, which was the first sheet "Daily Sales", five times, instead of changing sheets.  I needed to clarify the range sheet.

```
Range(Cells(1, 3 + Days), Cells(1, 32)).EntireColumn.Delete
```

Becomes:

```
Range(Deliveries.Cells(1,3+Days), Deliveries.Cells(1,32))_
.EntireColumn.Delete
```

Which is I think what R3uK was trying to tell me, but I didn't understand.  Thank you R3uK!